# Why would this cause a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException? Android

Tags: java, android, file, exception

I am working on a small file manager to help me learn the basics of android, but I keep running into an error. WHenever I have a lot of items in the folder, it crashes and I get a message similar to this one,

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=26; regionStart=23; regionLength=-2

What could be causing this? The line it points to is line 2:

```
1.)String mimeType = "";
2.)mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(f.getName());
```

Comment: something's wrong in one of those functions.

Comment: It doesn't 'cause a String out of bounds exception'. It causes a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.` Closer attention on your part to the actual exception type and its text basically would have given you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some key lines we need to see, such as where f (a File? a URI?) is defined. However when I have seen this problem before it was caused by a URI with no Protocol set.

Making sure you have an extension and using `MimeTypeMap#getMimeTypeFromExtension()` is probably a good bet too

Answer (score 0):

This error happens to me when the URL has a fragment, which can be identified by a `#` followed by some value. (For more on URL fragments, see https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_2_Fragments.html)

The URL fragment is not helpful in guessing content type, and since it is problematic in this case, it should be removed before calling `URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName()`.

Here is a simple function that returns a URL *without* the fragment:

```
private fun getSafeUrlForGuessing(url: String): String {
    return try {
        val uri = Uri.parse(url)
        if (uri.scheme?.startsWith("http") == true) {
            uri.buildUpon()
                    .fragment(null) // URLs with fragments cause URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName() to throw
                    .build()
                    .toString()
        } else {
            url
        }
    } catch (error: Throwable) {
        url
    }
}
```